# How to use cursor with set_block_property in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I created cursor to fetch data from database not use in data block oracle form

```
 DECLARE

 WCT  TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;

 CURSOR cursor1 IS
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME;

BEGIN
OPEN cursor1;
FETCH cursor1 INTO WCT;
CLOSE cursor1;

END;
```

I created search button and want search data with cursor

How to use this cursor with set_block_property in oracle forms 10g?

Comment: Which block property are you trying to set?  What are you trying to accomplish?  There is no relationship between cursors and `set_block_property`.  Read your cursor into a variable (which you are doing -- `WCT`) and then pass the variable into `set_block_property` as appropriate.  But I suspect there is something really, really wrong with what  you are trying to accomplish.  It is not normal to want to get block property values from the database.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a data block?

Comment: Code you posted seems OK, as far as syntax is concerned. Though, what do you plan to do once you select a single random value from TABLE_NAME into the WCT variable? In other words, I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve. As the others, I'm puzzled with your statement that says that you don't want to use a **data** block (does it mean that a **control** block is OK)? What "search" do you want to perform? What does it have to do with modifying block properties? Shortly - consider explaining the problem A LOT better.